# Installing vpython

Tags: python, vpython

I have installed vpython on the anaconda IDE. However when I import it and use a simple command

```
import vpython as v 
v.sphere()
```

Nothing appears. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on RHEL or Ubuntu? You might want to try reinstalling and making sure that the installation is correct. You can install from http://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html

Answer (score 0):

The person was using the newer vpython module, not the old visual module. See the first page of vpython.org. Perhaps you were not running in a Jupyter notebook? At the time the question was posted, the vpython module only worked when run in a Jupyter notebook, though now it can be used outside a Jupyter notebook.